# result errors using array io java

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, io

Contents of file `patch.txt`:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

#### My code:

```
int sum = 0;
Scanner s = new Scanner (new File("patch.txt"));
while (s.hasNextLine()){
            String [] str = s.nextLine().split("/r");
            for (int i=0; i<str.length; i++){
            sum+=Integer.parseInt(str[i]);
            }
            System.out.print(sum); //the result is 15
        }
        s.close();
    }
}
```

When I sum the data must be 15, but why do I always get an error?

Comment: why are you using split? " String [] str = s.nextLine().split("/r");" ?

Comment: because my data just one column and five rows...

Comment: s.nextLine gives you string representation of data. you can parse it without using split. You could use s.nextInt() to read ints. if you know your input is ints

Comment: @rickyhitman10 What means "but why always error"? Wich error?

Comment: if not use split it always error

Answer (score 2):

Solution using `for loop` and `array`:

```
String[] str = new String[10];
for(int i = 0; s.hasNextLine(); i++) {
    str[i] = s.nextLine();
    sum += Integer.parseInt(str[i]);
}
System.out.print(sum);
```

But for this problem given below is a better solution:

```
 while (s.hasNextLine()) {
        String str = s.nextLine();
        sum += Integer.parseInt(str);
 }
 System.out.print(sum);
```

Comment: i want to using for not while loops... :)

Comment: @rickyhitman10 This problem doesnot require a for loop if you need a for loop you can add `for(;s.hasNextLine();)` instead of `while(s.hasNextLine())`. But `while` loop is better

Comment: @rickyhitman10 i have edited and made the solution using for loop and array

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to do `String [] str = s.nextLine().split("/r")`, it is not needed. You were also printing the sum from within the while loop, but it should be outside the while loop. Try this:

```
while (s.hasNextLine()){
    String str = s.nextLine();          
    sum+=Integer.parseInt(str);         
}
System.out.print(sum); //the result is 15
s.close();
```

Comment: @rickyhitman10 Then you could replace the while loop with `for ( ; s.hasNextLine(); ) {` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try This :
Use a `try catch`for `Scanner` otherwise it shows the error `unreported exception java.io.FileNotFoundException;`

```
        import java.io.*;
        import  java.util.*;

        class Entry1 
        {
        static  Scanner s ;
        public static void main( String[] args )
        {
         int sum = 0;
          try
           {
             s = new Scanner (new File("patch.txt"));
           }
          catch(Exception e)
          {
            System.out.print(e);
          }
          while (s.hasNextLine())
          {      
            String [] str = s.nextLine().split("/r");
            for (int i=0; i<str.length; i++){
            sum+=Integer.parseInt(str[i]);
          }   
         }
        System.out.print(sum);
        s.close();
       }
      }
```

Comment: copy the code and run it. it's working fine on my system

Answer (score 0):

```
int sum = 0;
Scanner s = new Scanner (new File("patch.txt"));
while (s.hasNextLine()){
    String [] str = s.nextLine().split("\r");
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
        if(!str[i].trim().isEmpty){
            sum+=Integer.parseInt(str[i]);
        }
    }
}
s.close();
System.out.print(sum); //the result is 15
```

Try this.

Edited above code.

Comment: @rickyhitman10, does this work? Please let me as soon as possible. Because I will be leaving to home, and may not be available for helping you.